# Numpy merging arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have two arrays

```
 a = np.array[1,18,3,13,6,45,45]
 b= np.array [8,13,6,45,45]
```

after doing some matching exercises I have a list, such as:

```
[3,1,4]
```

first and second number of the list are zero based.  the third number is not.
the list stands for

- start position of first array
- start position of second array
- how many numbers rows to retrieve

so for this example the result would be

```
13, 13 
6,6
45,45
45,45
```

Both starting points of the array and then get 4 rows after that.

How can I merge my two arrays using my matchlist?

**EDIT**
This is the matchlist that I am using:

```
matchlist2 = []

matchlist2.append([3,1,4])
matchlist2.append([9,7,731])
matchlist2.append([766,762,19])
matchlist2.append([800,796,57])
matchlist2.append([867,862,88])
matchlist2.append([960,955,468])
matchlist2.append([1432,1427,65])
matchlist2.append([1523,1518,341])
matchlist2.append([1873,1868,32])
matchlist2.append([1923,1916,82])
matchlist2.append([2011,2004,699])
matchlist2.append([2716,2707,902])
matchlist2.append([3628,3617,247])
matchlist2.append([3923,391,378])
matchlist2.append([4306,4292,5])
```

Comment: Given, `l = [3,1,4]` : `a[l[0]:l[0]+l[2]] , b[l[1]:l[1]+l[2]]`?

Comment: What data structure would your result have to be in? A 2 column array? Or would you need a list of tuples?

Comment: @Saravana Kumar , it would have to be in a 2 column array  thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it something like this:

```
result = np.array([[[a[ind[0]],b[ind[1]]] for ind in zip(range(ml[0],ml[0]+ml[2]),range(ml[1],ml[1]+ml[2]))] for ml in matchlist2])
```

Edit: Divakar's solution is actually much more elegant. If you just zip it up you'd get what you need.

```
result = [list(zip(a[l[0]:l[0]+l[2]],b[l[1]:l[1]+l[2]])) for l in matchlist2]
```

Comment: I am getting this error: TypeError: slice indices must be integers or None or have an __index__ method.  I may just be doing something wrong though

Comment: Well can you see what your matchlist looks like? For some reason python thinks the elements of your matchlist are not integers.

Comment: I included the matchlist that I am using

Comment: Alright so your matchlist is actually a 2D array. Let me edit my answer.

Comment: How do you display the contents of the merged list?  I only see "<zip object at 0x......"

Comment: Zip returns a zip iterator. So you should be able to loop through the zip object and print each element.

Comment: how do you loop through the zip object?

Comment: I've edited the answer to fit your requirement. Check it out. Basically you can convert the zip object to a list to achieve what you need.

Comment: thank you so much for your help.  I haven't used this function before, so I'm not sure how do I get the final output in an array.  I was able to get a list with the multiple tuples, but I'm not sure how to get the entire set in an array.

Comment: There's not much difference between a tuple and a list except that a tuple is immutable which means you can't change the value inside a tuple. But if you REALLY want it as a list, I've modified my original answer (not divakar's approach) to do what you need.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you need:

```
a = np.array([1,18,3,13,6,45,45])
b = np.array([8,13,6,45,45])

look = [3,1,4]
first, second, step = look
c = np.array(zip(a[first:first+step],b[second:second+step]))
c
#[[13 13 
# [ 6  6
# [45 45
# [45 45]]
```

Comment: I am using spyder, and when I get 'object arrays are currently not supported'